# How can I change my c++ code to use classes instead of struct

Tags: c++, class, struct

Hey guys how can I achieve changing this piece of code to use classes instead of a struct. I briefly understand how classes work but im completely confused how to change this piece of code thanks. The code it's self is to scan a .txt file and then search the .txt file to select a word then print the results.

The basic layout would consist of

```
class Word {
public:
      string word;
      string definition;
      int usageFrequency;
private:
```

Comment: The pointers in `main` are completely unnecessary.

Comment: `class` and `struct` are the same except `class` defaults to private access and `struct` defaults to public.

Comment: Please don't destroy your posts. This is inappropriate.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, `struct` and `class` are identical except for the default access allowed - `class` is `private` while `struct` is `public`. There's no need to convert, what you have is just fine.

As a matter of convention usually `struct` is reserved for structures that don't have any methods. However I've found that adding a constructor or `operator<` and `operator==` is perfectly acceptable and is very convenient.

Comment: Hey thanks, I'd like to change it to a class though.

Comment: @subzerok Then change it to a class. Just substitute `struct` with `class` and add a `public:` after the opening brace `{`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between struct and class is that struct members are public by default and in class they are private by default. Here is a struct Word converted to class, the only modification you need:

```
class Word {
public:
    string word;         
    string definition;   
    int usageFrequency;  

    //Constructor
    Word(const string &theWord, const string &theDefinition)
    {
        word = theWord;
        definition = theDefinition;
        usageFrequency = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: You are missing one difference: `struct`'s base classes are `public` by default, `class`' are `private`.